# Beginner trying out onClickListener in fragment. It keep crashing in runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Java/android develop and trying to follow instructions from android site but cannot find clear answer to implementing onclicklistener in fragment.  Please help me why its keep crashing in runtime when I click.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mngr_user, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDBhelper = new UserBaseHelper(getActivity());


        // Capture our button from layout
        TextView TextviewShow = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_show);

        // Register of onClick listener with the implementation above
        TextviewShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something when the text_show is clicked
                displayInfo();

            }
        });
     }

.....

}
```

Comment: change this `(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_show);` to `(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_show);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**use this**

```
 TextView TextviewShow = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_show);
```

**instead of this**

```
    TextView TextviewShow = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_show);
```

**change your code as below**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mngr_user, container, false);

         // Capture our button from layout
        TextView TextviewShow = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_show);

        // Register of onClick listener with the implementation above
        TextviewShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something when the text_show is clicked
                displayInfo();

            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
     View v;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mngr_user, container, false);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mDBhelper = new UserBaseHelper(getActivity());


            // Capture our button from layout
            TextView TextviewShow = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_show);

            // Register of onClick listener with the implementation above
            TextviewShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do something when the text_show is clicked
                    displayInfo();

                }
            });
         }

    .....

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your code from `onCreate()` method to `onCreateView()` method and change the following code

From

```
(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_show);
```

to

```
(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_show);
```